# How can I get eclipse to default to 'deselect working set'

Tags: java, eclipse

When I start eclipse, the project explorer window shows none of my projects. If I open the menu in the project explorer, it shows "Multiple Working Sets" as being selected. In order to see my projects, I have to click on "Deselect working set", and then all the projects magically appear. What's going on? How can I configure eclipse so that I see all my projects by default?

Comment: It is by default viewing `Project as Top Element Level` (and not showing as workings set), and it should also be saved in your workspace settings.

Comment: @flafoux - Thank you that does work, but there are times when I find it easier to have `Project` as `Top Level Elements`, and for this, I'd like the default to be not have a working set. It is a relatively minor problem, but it does annoy me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Menu -> Select Working Set... -> No Working Set

EDIT: Sorry, this was incorrect, doing so will disable working sets only until restart. Better solution is Project Explorer Menu -> Select Working Set... -> Selected Working Sets and select all working sets available.

You have to repeat this every time you add new working set (at least this is the way it works for me)

Answer (score 0):

I don't generally use Eclipse working sets.

In my case, I started having to manually "Deselect Working Set" after I imported a couple of 3rd party projects that *DID* happen be a part of a "working set".

SOLUTION:

1. Enable Add to Working Set/Remove from Working Set menu item:

```
   Eclipse > Window > Customize Perspective > Command Groups Availability >
     Window Working Setup= Y
     Working Set Manipulation= Y
```

2. `Project Explorer > Select` offending project
3. `Edit > Remove from Working Set` (in this case, removed from "Uncategorized projects")

Voila.  Everything works as expected again :)

Answer (score 0):

A work around that worked for me is by removing all projects from working sets:
select all projects > context menu > Assign Working Sets...
Click Deselect All and then click Ok

Next restart, I can see all my projects without having to "Deselect working set".